# How to throw error in an async function in jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

How do i test if the function `createTempUsageStatisticsTable(athenaExpress)` throws an error and also to test if `createTempUsageStatisticsTable(athenaExpress)` throws error because the function `athenaExpress.query(athenaQueryParam)` throws an error (Using Jest) ? (Assume filename to be `index.js`)

```
async function createTempUsageStatisticsTable(athenaExpress) {
  let athenaQueryParam = {
      sql: getSqlQueries.CREATE_DEVICE_USAGE_STATS_TEMP_TABLE_QUERY,
      db: "testdb"
  };
      await athenaExpress.query(athenaQueryParam);
}
exportFunctions={createTempUsageStatisticsTable:createTempUsageStatisticsTable}

module.exports=exportFunctions
```

Now,I want to write a test to test if `createTempUsageStatisticsTable(athenaExpress)` throws an error when `athenaExpress.query(athenaQueryParam)`throws an error or rejects a promise in a mock implementation whichever is suitable or works,so i did

```
    const confError = new Error('network error');
    athenaExpress.query = jest.fn().mockImplementationOnce(() => {
        throw new Error(confError);    // tried this 
        promise.reject(confError);
    })
    index.configureAthenaExpress();
    expect(index.configureAthenaExpress).toThrow();
```

However tests do not seem to pass please help

Thanks to James i got it working,However i slightly tweaked his code as i was getting some error due to strict equal,The code is as follows:

```
test("createTempUsageStatisticsTable throws an exception if 
    athenaExpress.query fails()", async () => {

    const creaError=new Error("network error")
    athenaExpress=configureAthenaExpress();
    athenaExpress.query.mockRejectedValueOnce(creaError);
    await expect(createTempUsageStatisticsTable(athenaExpress)).rejects.toBe(creaError);
  });
```

Comment: use `try{......}catch(e){......}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on how `athenaExpress` is exported, you can mock `query` to throw and then test for the existence of said by leveraging [`rejects`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/tutorial-async#rejects) e.g.

```
const createTempUsageStatisticsTable = require("./createTempUsageStatisticsTable");
const athenaExpress = require("./athenaExpress");

jest.mock("./athenaExpress");

test("createTempUsageStatisticsTable throws if query fails", async () => {
  athenaExpress.query.mockRejectedValueOnce(new Error("network error"));
  await expect(createTempUsageStatisticsTable(athenaExpress)).rejects.toMatchObject({ message: "network error" });
});
```

Comment: This works however i think you missed `.toEqual` or `.toBe` after rejects also this was generating some error due to strict equals so i modified it a bit,I have updated the modified version if you want to refer... Anyways much thanks James appreciate your help :)

Comment: @AliKhan whoops, that was a typo (I was half asleep and writing on mobile device). In terms of the equal checking, that again would've been because `toThrow` does partial matching, you should be able to use `toMatchObject` rather than referencing the same error instance throughout which isn't a realistic test. Either way I think I offered enough to answer the question ;)

Comment: Yes accepted the answer :) your solution worked wonders for my tests....